# imap_append not working with attachments

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, imap, email-attachments

I'm trying to copy emails into my sent folder using php's imap_append function. It works perfectly fine on emails without attachments. However, if I add an attachment it seems to spring out an error:

```
Notice: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2) in Unknown
```

Oddly, if I attach a .txt file with a few lines the attachment comes through, but if I attach a pdf/word document/etc it gives out the above error.

I have checked the headers/body/attachments and all appear to be fine to the best of my knowledge. I am using PHPMailer version 5.

PHP code below:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.livemail.co.uk";
$mail->Username = "xxx@xxx.com";  
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->CharSet    = "UTF-8";
$mail->From       = "xxx@xxx.co.uk";
$mail->FromName   = "Test";
$mail->Subject = "Testing";
$mail->AltBody = "Testing";
$mail->MsgHTML("<body><h1>Hello, this is a test</h1></body>");
$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.co.uk", "xxx");
$mail->AddAttachment("attachment.docx");

$mail->Send();

// We would like to append message into our sent folder at this point 
$connection_string = "{mail.livemail.co.uk:993/imap/ssl}Sent Items";

$stream = imap_open($connection_string, "xxx@xxx.co.uk", "xxx");

imap_append($stream,$connection_string,$mail->CreateHeader() . $mail->CreateBody());
```

Headers

```
Date: Thu, 16 Nov 2017 19:30:43 +0000
Return-Path: xxx@xxx.co.uk
To: xxx <xxx@xxx.co.uk>
From: xxx <xxx@xxx.co.uk>
Subject: Testing
Message-ID: <e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c@localhost>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="b1_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c"


--b1_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b2_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c"

--b2_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset = "UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


Testing


--b2_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


<body><h1>Hello, this is a test</h1></body>



--b2_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c--
--b1_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="attachment.docx"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="attachment.docx"
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--b1_e92d6eed5e3b708416fb06661aeaab2c--
```

To update this, I am using an older version of PHPMailer:

```
  /**
   * Assembles the message body.  Returns an empty string on failure.
   * @access public
   * @return string The assembled message body
   */
  public function CreateBody() {
    $body = '';

    if ($this->sign_key_file) {
      $body .= $this->GetMailMIME();
    }

    $this->SetWordWrap();

    switch($this->message_type) {
      case 'alt':
        $body .= $this->GetBoundary($this->boundary[1], '', 'text/plain', '');
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->AltBody, $this->Encoding);
        $body .= $this->LE.$this->LE;
        $body .= $this->GetBoundary($this->boundary[1], '', 'text/html', '');
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->Body, $this->Encoding);
        $body .= $this->LE.$this->LE;
        $body .= $this->EndBoundary($this->boundary[1]);
        break;
      case 'plain':
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->Body, $this->Encoding);
        break;
      case 'attachments':
        $body .= $this->GetBoundary($this->boundary[1], '', '', '');
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->Body, $this->Encoding);
        $body .= $this->LE;
        $body .= $this->AttachAll();
        break;
      case 'alt_attachments':
        $body .= sprintf("--%s%s", $this->boundary[1], $this->LE);
        $body .= sprintf("Content-Type: %s;%s" . "\tboundary=\"%s\"%s", 'multipart/alternative', $this->LE, $this->boundary[2], $this->LE.$this->LE);
        $body .= $this->GetBoundary($this->boundary[2], '', 'text/plain', '') . $this->LE; // Create text body
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->AltBody, $this->Encoding);
        $body .= $this->LE.$this->LE;
        $body .= $this->GetBoundary($this->boundary[2], '', 'text/html', '') . $this->LE; // Create the HTML body
        $body .= $this->EncodeString($this->Body, $this->Encoding);
        $body .= $this->LE.$this->LE;
        $body .= $this->EndBoundary($this->boundary[2]);
        $body .= $this->AttachAll();
        break;
    }

    if ($this->IsError()) {
      $body = '';
    } elseif ($this->sign_key_file) {
      try {
        $file = tempnam('', 'mail');
        file_put_contents($file, $body); //TODO check this worked
        $signed = tempnam("", "signed");
        if (@openssl_pkcs7_sign($file, $signed, "file://".$this->sign_cert_file, array("file://".$this->sign_key_file, $this->sign_key_pass), NULL)) {
          @unlink($file);
          @unlink($signed);
          $body = file_get_contents($signed);
        } else {
          @unlink($file);
          @unlink($signed);
          throw new phpmailerException($this->Lang("signing").openssl_error_string());
        }
      } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $body = '';
        if ($this->exceptions) {
          throw $e;
        }
      }
    }

    return $body;
  }

  /**
   * Assembles message header.
   * @access public
   * @return string The assembled header
   */
  public function CreateHeader() {
    $result = '';

    // Set the boundaries
    $uniq_id = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $this->boundary[1] = 'b1_' . $uniq_id;
    $this->boundary[2] = 'b2_' . $uniq_id;

    if($this->Timezone=='' || $this->Timezone==0) $this->Timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($this->Timezone);
    $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Date', self::RFCDate($this->Timezone));
    if($this->Sender == '') {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', trim($this->From));
    } else {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Return-Path', trim($this->Sender));
    }

    // To be created automatically by mail()
    if($this->Mailer != 'mail') {
      if ($this->SingleTo === true) {
        foreach($this->to as $t) {
          $this->SingleToArray[] = $this->AddrFormat($t);
        }
      } else {
        if(count($this->to) > 0) {
          $result .= $this->AddrAppend('To', $this->to);
        } elseif (count($this->cc) == 0) {
          $result .= $this->HeaderLine('To', 'undisclosed-recipients:;');
        }
      }
    }

    $from = array();
    $from[0][0] = trim($this->From);
    $from[0][1] = $this->FromName;
    $result .= $this->AddrAppend('From', $from);

    // sendmail and mail() extract Cc from the header before sending
    if(count($this->cc) > 0) {
      $result .= $this->AddrAppend('Cc', $this->cc);
    }

    // sendmail and mail() extract Bcc from the header before sending
    if((($this->Mailer == 'sendmail') || ($this->Mailer == 'mail')) && (count($this->bcc) > 0)) {
      $result .= $this->AddrAppend('Bcc', $this->bcc);
    }

    if(count($this->ReplyTo) > 0) {
      $result .= $this->AddrAppend('Reply-to', $this->ReplyTo);
    }

    // mail() sets the subject itself
    if($this->Mailer != 'mail') {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Subject', $this->EncodeHeader($this->SecureHeader($this->Subject)));
    }

    if($this->MessageID != '') {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Message-ID',$this->MessageID);
    } else {
      $result .= sprintf("Message-ID: <%s@%s>%s", $uniq_id, $this->ServerHostname(), $this->LE);
    }
    $result .= $this->HeaderLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority);
    $result .= $this->HeaderLine('X-Mailer', 'PHPMailer '.$this->Version.' (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)');

    if($this->ConfirmReadingTo != '') {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Disposition-Notification-To', '<' . trim($this->ConfirmReadingTo) . '>');
    }

    // Add custom headers
    for($index = 0; $index < count($this->CustomHeader); $index++) {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine(trim($this->CustomHeader[$index][0]), $this->EncodeHeader(trim($this->CustomHeader[$index][1])));
    }
    if (!$this->sign_key_file) {
      $result .= $this->HeaderLine('MIME-Version', '1.0');
      $result .= $this->GetMailMIME();
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

The above two functions are exactly how Send() is calling the body/header.

Anyone got any ideas? Can't find anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

[One of the PHPMailer examples shows IMAP upload](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L81), though I've not tried it with attachments. I suspect that the problem lies in how you're creating the message to upload; I don't know where you got this from:

```
$mail->CreateHeader() . $mail->CreateBody()
```

That will not work properly as there is no separator between header and body, likely resulting in an unusable message. PHPMailer has a built-in function to get the whole message for you: `getSentMIMEMessage()`, so to upload a copy of the message you should do this instead:

```
$result = imap_append($imapStream, $path, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
```

and compare the rest of the example with your code.

Comment: I believe I am using an older version, 

 Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class                                    |
|   Version: 5.1                                                            |
|   Contact: via sourceforge.net support pages (also www.worxware.com)      |
|      Info: http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net                               |
|   Support: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ 

There is no such function "getSentMIMEMessage()" in my version. No I can't upgrade. 

What do you mean no separator between? The header pasted is perfectly fine is it not?

Comment: That version is *very* old (2009), buggy, and vulnerable to attack, so I suggest you update immediately. If you visit the sourceforge project you will see that it tells you that it's no longer supported there and that you should [go to github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I see. I'm sadly editing a script that isn't mine called Sendy to add in this functionality.  I have added those two functions above in my code if it helps.

Comment: Seriously, the version you're running is **dangerous**. There have been numerous security holes with known public exploits that can compromise your whole server, not to mention the literally hundreds of bugs fixed in the last 8 years. If Sendy is still distributing this old version, you should scrap it and use something better. Ask Sendy to support the commercial software you paid them for.

Comment: Yes, I agree you're correct. I just installed separately the newest version of PHPMailer and it appears to not have this issue.  I was hoping for a workaround but seems like I'll have to find out whether there is another version of Sendy with the updated PHPMailer distribution. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: I had the same issue with an old version of PHPMailer. Updating to the latest version resolved this issue.